# appending text on command line - not in file

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I'm looking to create an alias as a shortcut to get to log files.  The directory I want to end up in is the month and day.  Assuming the first part of the path is /some/path, I want to append the results of "date +%m%d" to the path.  So for example, typing in an alias of "gotologs" (alias gotologs='cd /some/path/ this is where I need help') would result in
cd /some/path/0104

I use bash at home, korn shell at work if that matters

Thanks in advance

Comment: `alias gotologs='cd /some/path/$(date +%m%d)'`. Is this what you are looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
alias gotologs='cd /some/path/$(date +%m%d)'
```